# Navigator does not display the child component

Tags: react-native

I am using Navigator to move to a child component from a parent component. The Navigator works correctly and successfully executes the render method of the child component. But nothing is displayed on the screen.

What am I missing from the navigator that I cannot display the child component?

I have used similar code for a test navigator and I was able to display the child component.

Here is the code for the Parent View

```
'use strict';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  Navigator,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';

var Profile = require('./Profile');
var UpdateVehicles = require('./UpdateVehicles');

var ROUTES = {
  'profile': Profile,
  'updateVehicles': UpdateVehicles,
};

class ProfileBase extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        style={styles.container}
        initialRoute={{name:'profile'}}
        renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}/>
    );
  }
  renderScene(route, navigator) {
    var Mycomponent = ROUTES[route.name];
    return <Mycomponent route={route} navigator={navigator}/>;
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});

module.exports = ProfileBase;
```

And, the child Profile view's code is here,

```
'use strict';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
var Parse = require('parse/react-native');
var Button = require('./Button');

class Profile extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: "default",
      userEmail: "",
      licensePlate: [],
      registeredState: [],
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
    var userJSON = JSON.stringify(currentUser);
    var userinfo = eval ("(" + userJSON + ")");
    this.setState({username: userinfo.username});
    this.setState({userEmail: userinfo.email});
    var vehicle = Parse.Object.extend("Vehicle");
    var query = new Parse.Query(vehicle);
    query.equalTo("userEmail", userinfo.email);
    query.find({
      success: (results) => {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          var object = results[i];
          this.setState({
                 licensePlate: this.state.licensePlate.concat([object.get('licensePlate')]),
                 registeredState: this.state.registeredState.concat([object.get('registeredState')]),
            });
        }
      },
      error: (error) => {
        console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log("reached");
    const { page } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.titleContainer}>
          Hi! {this.state.username}
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.titleContainer}>
          Your registered vehicles are,
        </Text>
        {this.displayCars()}
        <Button text="Edit vehicles" onPress={this.updateVehicleInfo.bind(this)}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
  displayCars() {
    return this.state.licensePlate.map((str,index) => {
      return (<View><Text style={styles.titleContainer}>Vehicle {index+1}: {str}</Text></View>);
    })
  }
  updateVehicleInfo() {
    this.props.navigator.push({name: 'updateVehicles'});
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  titleContainer: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
});

module.exports = Profile;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the `style={styles.container}` with the `flex:1` style attribute from the navigator.

See the example I've made here: https://rnplay.org/apps/guargQ

I've commented out the line with flex:1. If you add it back in, the screen turns blank.